# Unity 5.2 sudden VR crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

All of a sudden, I am getting a full blown crash whenever I run/play my project with the native VR support in `Unity 5.2.0f3` and `Oculus version 1.7 (SDK 0.6.0.1)` which has never happened before, until today out of the blue. No change made to anything to do with VR or Oculus that might have triggered it, hence my confusion...

This is what I get on the log:

```
Unity Editor [version: Unity 5.2.0f3_e7947df39b5c]

OVRPlugin.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module OVRPlugin.dll at 0033:eb9a3b9a.
```

My PC and GC:
- Windows 7
- Nvidia GTX980 Ti

Thanks in advance for your help,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe 5.2 requires SDK 0.7.0 for native VR support. Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: No, I have not upgraded. I am hesitant, as I can currently run everything perfectly. I mean everything was perfect until this happened...

Comment: Is there any way to have 2 SDK installs, similar to Unity that you can specify a different folder name and have, for example, both Unity 4.6 and unity 5.1 on the same machine?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that, but 0.7.0 was a big upgrade IMO (whereas 5.2 was more a mix of pro and con). You could always uninstall and go back to 0.6.0.

Comment: mmm... OK. I will do that if by tomorrow nothing has helped. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Got same error with Unity 5.3.3f1. Fixed it by changing **Oculus Config Util** settings as following:

1. Open Oculus Config Util App on windows.
2. Go to Tools->Service->Configure options.
3. Set the Debug HMD type to DK2.

might be help for new users.